# How to generate a JWK from a PEM encoded public key in Java?

Tags: java, jwt, bouncycastle, jwk

I have a PEM encoded public key and want to generate a JWK key from it in Java. This is what I tried:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwGhr2bd1u5JVSWEQjo+UWfH1pE0iK9lm
C//yb5my5PnQ2O62etGX3odWvb10J95pWvhahQcC8wPnjvedZtBxcgHiFOprbYYgZWcXarpw9EO6
H/brPiK1h4akjgNxTdBsFHikzaZ1Erd3T4FEzop8j4pRNrjA/tUHEqxdqOl7H0xHJmbv9odn4Mmq
E/azyohY8LhZ/+YUNbEAT3RCb1Z64tUHow4K+K3QFbNTcEQdN69wNvuAskYsSPCR2f8c6hYShhdf
s8NxnGAKgb9APWvkbLw8+n2/sbHyCmWw5ofW1LokXiCxczqK87UCPMaqFwOt2rlBNrzoMMzWAmH7
s9O6qQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Java method using [com.nimbusds.jose.jwk](https://bitbucket.org/connect2id/nimbus-jose-jwt/src/master/) and [vert.x](https://vertx.io/)'s [JsonObject](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/json/JsonObject.html):

```java
  String getJWTKey(final String rawKey) throws Exception {
    final KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    final SubjectPublicKeyInfo pubKeyInfo =
        (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) new PEMParser(new StringReader(rawKey)).readObject();
    final X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKeyInfo.getEncoded());
    final RSAPublicKey rsaPubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);

    // How to get these two?
    List<Base64> certChain = null;
    Base64URL thumbprint = null;

    final RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaPubKey)
        .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
        .algorithm(new Algorithm("RS256"))
        .keyID("mykey")
        .x509CertChain(certChain)
        .x509CertSHA256Thumbprint(thumbprint)
        .build();
 
    return key.toJSONString();
```

The result is:

```json
{
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "use": "sig",
      "alg" : "RS256",
      "kid": "mykey",
      "n": "wGhr2bd1u5JVSWEQjo-UWfH1pE0iK9lmC__yb5my5PnQ2O62etGX3odWvb10J95pWvhahQcC8wPnjvedZtBxcgHiFOprbYYgZWcXarpw9EO6H_brPiK1h4akjgNxTdBsFHikzaZ1Erd3T4FEzop8j4pRNrjA_tUHEqxdqOl7H0xHJmbv9odn4MmqE_azyohY8LhZ_-YUNbEAT3RCb1Z64tUHow4K-K3QFbNTcEQdN69wNvuAskYsSPCR2f8c6hYShhdfs8NxnGAKgb9APWvkbLw8-n2_sbHyCmWw5ofW1LokXiCxczqK87UCPMaqFwOt2rlBNrzoMMzWAmH7s9O6qQ"
    }
  ]
}
```

Looking at [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-set-properties) I'm missing:

- x5c
- x5t

What do I miss in my code? A solution using [**bouncycastle**](https://www.bouncycastle.org/documentation.html) would be very much welcome. I have access to the cert file (self generated) if required

Comment: `"alg"` is optional, as stated in rfc7517 linked from the page you link, but there is a builder method `.algorithm(String)` to set it if you want it. Similarly `"x5c"` and `"x5t"` apply only if you have a cert chain or thumbprint respectively, which you don't show; if you do have such, there are builder methods for them. Bouncy doesn't support JOSE/JWK, but it (bcpkix+bcprov) does most PEM, which could replace your first 7 lines by about 2.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thx for chipping in. Updated the code with the alg. wonder how I get the values for x5t and x5c to feed into the builder method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the way I learned that I need the certificate besides the public key. So the 2 method solution (until I learn better) is:

```java
/**
   * Returns the JSON formatted JWK based on provided public key / cert
   *
   * @param rawKey - public key as read from disk in pem format
   * @param cert - certificate as read from disk in pem format
   * @return JWK Key as Optional<String>
   */
  public static Optional<String> getJwkString(final String rawKey, final String cert) {
    try {
      final KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      final CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
      final SubjectPublicKeyInfo pubKeyInfo =
          (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) new PEMParser(new StringReader(rawKey)).readObject();
      final X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(pubKeyInfo.getEncoded());
      final RSAPublicKey rsaPubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);

      final X509Certificate rsaCert =
          (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.getBytes()));
      final byte[] certEncoded = rsaCert.getEncoded();
      final List<Base64> certChain = new ArrayList<>();
      certChain.add(Base64.encode(certEncoded));

      final Base64URL thumbprint = Base64URL.from(getThumbprint(certEncoded));

      final RSAKey key = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaPubKey)
          .keyUse(KeyUse.SIGNATURE)
          .algorithm(new Algorithm("RS256"))
          .x509CertChain(certChain)
          .x509CertThumbprint(thumbprint)
          .keyID("mykey")
          .build();

      return Optional.of(key.toJSONString());

    } catch (final Exception e) {
      SamlResourceUtils.logger.error(e);
    }

    return Optional.empty();
  }

  public static String getThumbprint(final byte[] bytes)
      throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    md.update(bytes);
    return Hex.toHexString(md.digest());
  }
```

`getThumbprint` using `java.security.MessageDigest`. Full import (not all classes are relevant here):

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.nimbusds.jose.Algorithm;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.KeyUse;
import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
import com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64;
import com.nimbusds.jose.util.Base64URL;

import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex;
```

Comment: Which library are you using for `SamlResourceUtils`, it doesn't look like it's in nimbus-jose-jwt.  I am using Guava's `Hashing.sha256().hashBytes(certEncoded).toString()` and it seems to be working, but I want to be sure.

Comment: getThumbprint uses java.security.MessageDigest, full import see above

Comment: I am new to this technology. Where does the ID "myKey" come from? Is it derived from the public key or is it an arbitrary value? If the former, how do you extract it?

Comment: "myKey" is just the name you give it. You could call it "Wanderlust"